# Get page permalink without wpurl

Tags: permalinks

I currently have an ID of a page that I want to use its permalink as the front of a permastruct of a CPT I'm setting up.

Now I can use get_permalink() but that returns the full URL:

`http://www.example.com/imapage/subpage/subsubpage`

but all I want to return is `imapage/subpage/subsubpage`

Is there a function that can do this or do I have to device something that can subtract the non-needed part of the url?

Comment: **Related:** [Get Permalink without domain (i.e. get relative permalink)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/63323/10691)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing built in to return the bit you want but it should be as easy as using the home_url() function and removing it's output from the full url eg:

```
function get_relative_permalink( $url ) {
    return str_replace( home_url(), "", $url );
}
```

Comment: I came to the same bit of code but was hoping for some function already in core that returns it the way I want.

Comment: That will result in maybe unexpected values for multisite or with WordPress installed in sub directory.

Answer (score 24):

There's actually a core function for this now. `wp_make_link_relative($url)`

> Convert full URL paths to relative paths.
>
> Removes the http or https protocols and the domain. Keeps the path '/' at the beginning, so it isn't a true relative link, but from the web root base.

**Example**

```
<?php echo wp_make_link_relative('http://localhost/wp_test/sample-page/'); ?>
```

This will output `/wp_test/sample-page/`

**Example with Post ID**
`<?php echo wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>`

**Example for current post**
`<?php echo wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink()); ?>`

More about this can be found in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_make_link_relative).

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct one, because it uses a built-in helper function of WordPress Core: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_link_relative/

Comment: not the best decision, because if you are started your WP in localhost via MAMP and you have multiple projects on localhost/*, the answer to `wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink())` will be `/wp_dir/category_slug`

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to use `get_permalink()` for that.

If you dig into the code for that function in `/wp-includes/link-template.php` you'll see why.  After the permalink structure is parsed and prepared, the code does this:

```
$permalink = home_url( str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink) );
```

This is performed immediately after the structure of the link is created and before anything is passed through a useful filter.

So unfortunately, you'll have to extract the non-needed part of the URL yourself.  I'd recommend using the `str_replace()` function that @sanchothefat suggested.

Answer (score 3):

`$path = parse_url(get_permalink(...), PHP_URL_PATH);` ... gives the **URL PATH** only. This is not relative to blog root but to domain. It's the absolute URI.

Answer (score 1):

```
$relative_permalink = wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink($post->ID));
```

[wp_make_link_relative( string $link )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_link_relative/)

> Removes the http or https protocols and the domain. Keeps the path ‘/’
> at the beginning, so it isn’t a true relative link, but from the web
> root base.