# Get Permalink without domain (i.e. get relative permalink)

Tags: permalinks

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php echo str_replace( home_url(), '', get_permalink($post->ID) ); ?>
```

What it does is output the permalink as a relative URL i.e. only the slug. For instance, if the permalink is `http://example.com/2012/01/post-title/`, the relative URL output by the code would look like `/2012/01/post-title/`.

**Problem:** All Posts and Pages show the right permalink, which is great. But all other pages (including Home, Search and Archives) show the relative URL of the first post and not that of the respective pages. Any idea why? What am I doing wrong here?

**Reference:** [Get page permalink without wpurl](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/32728/10691)

---

**EDIT:** Here's what else I've tried:

**In functions.php**

```
function get_relative_permalink( $url ) {
    $url = get_permalink();
    return str_replace( home_url(), "", $url );
}
```

**In header.php**

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-IN" href="http://in.example.com/<?php echo get_relative_permalink(); ?>" />
```

Same problem with this as well. But this one shows a not-so-informative error too.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying this code....?? Are you using `global $post` before your above code?

Comment: @JoshuaAbenazer I am using the code as it is in my header.php file — looks like that's the wrong way of doing it. I will edit my question to reflect whatelse I've tried, so that you can help me better.

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want this?

Comment: @TomJNowell Hey. I need to use a different domain for this markup: `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-IN" href="http://in.example.com/2012/01/post-title/" />` — but the actual permalink is like this: `http://example.com/2012/01/post-title/`. ([Reading this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077) will give you a better idea of what I am doing.)

Comment: If you want to go **the WP way**, you must realize `get_permalink()` is for getting instances of class `WP_Post` links (posts, pages, custom post types, ... )... for archives, tags, etc - just categories in general - instances of class `WP_Term` - it is `get_term_link()`, for home it is `home_url()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `get_permalink()` to grab the current URL. `get_permalink` will give you the full address of the current post, not the address of the URL visited.

e.g. for example.com/test/page `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` prints `/test/page`

Note that this doesn't include the hashtag, as that part never gets sent to the server, and it also doesn't include `?foo=bar` type parameters, those are in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: Works perfectly!!! Small correction — the second code is missing a quote. `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` — and thanks!

Comment: @TomJNowell If I am not mistaken, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will give you the *current* URL, which may be a problem if it is a paginated post, meaning that /test/page/2 will be grabbed while using get_permalink() would be the solution for this issue. Am I making sense?

Comment: Which is similar to what the original authors issue was, I would have to do some testing, but you can always add your own answer and if it works I'll upvote =]

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It doesn't even remotely answer the OP's question!

Comment: @JimMaguire it is defintely related to what OP asked, however answer author forgot to mention that it returns basically EVERYTHING after domain up to hash (which is not sent to server by design). *So it is just a starting point, **not** the final solution.*

Comment: **Get somewhat final solution:** **a)** `explode()` the string by `?` and keep only the first`[0]` part to remove *possible* GET query **b)** run (regexp) replace (`preg_replace()`) to remove any possible "pretty url parameters", most commonly `page/N/` - page number and other possible params can change, that's why regexp... e.g. `preg_replace( '/\/page\/\d+\//', '/', $url )`

Answer (score 17):

I use

```
str_replace(home_url(), '', get_permalink());
```

If site root is not `/`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work when WP is in a subdirectory...

Comment: What do you mean, when WP is in a subdirectory?

Comment: @JimMaguire `http://example.com/not-the-root-dir/`

Comment: No need to str_replace or preg_replace, just pass the permalink to [wp_make_link_relative][1]().


  [1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_link_relative/

The built-in function is much simpler and also neatly handles trailing slashes, situations where home_url and site_url are different and various other edge cases.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
function force_relative_url ($url)
{
    return preg_replace ('/^(http)?s?:?\/\/[^\/]*(\/?.*)$/i', '$2', '' . $url);
}
```

To use it on a permalink:

```
$relative_permalink = force_relative_url (get_permalink ($post->ID));
```